# Equivalente de lp en Windows

Tags: linux, windows, imprimir

En Linux con el comando lp y el nombre del fichero, lo imprime desde el terminal, incluso un pdf.
¿Hay en Windows un comando similar que hago esto sin tener que usar adobe reader u otro programa similar?
Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El comando es `lpr` y es posible que debas habilitarlo como característica de windows.

[Respuesta en SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/420409/print-using-lpr-command-in-64-bit-windows)